# How do I filter by "date is null"?

Tags: views

I have a contacts view which includes birth date. I want to filter by the date not being set.

When I add a filter on the date, it provides a range of options (for example, *greater than* or *less than*), but not one for *is null*.

How can I add that?
Is there some configuration or another module to provide this functionality?